# TrinityRNASeq Error, at least one thread died

Tags: linux

Hi I tried to run the following in Trinity:

```
Trinity --seqType fq --SS_lib_type RF --max_memory 20G --left output_forward_paired.fq.gz --right output_reverse_paired.fq.gz --CPU 10
```

and I received the error:

```
Error encountered with thread.
Error, at least one thread died at /misc/scratch2/software/anaconda/envs/trinity-2.11-with-workaround/opt/trinity-2.15.1/util/insilico_read_normalization.pl line 434.
Error, cmd: /misc/scratch2/software/anaconda/envs/trinity-2.11-with-workaround/opt/trinity-2.15.1/util/insilico_read_normalization.pl --seqType fq --JM 20G --max_cov 200 --min_cov 1 --CPU 10 --output /misc/scratch3/TrinityRun1/trinity_out_dir/insilico_read_normalization --max_CV 10000 --SS_lib_type RF --left /misc/scratch3/TrinityRun1/output_forward_paired.fq.gz --right /misc/scratch3/TrinityRun1/output_reverse_paired.fq.gz --pairs_together --PARALLEL_STATS died with ret 6400 at /scratch2/software/anaconda/envs/trinity-2.11-with-workaround/bin/Trinity line 2919.
```

I've never used this tool before so any help is appreciated thank you!

Comment: How much RAM do you have available? 256GB? How many reads? Try lowering your CPU count (i.e. `--CPU 1`) and see if you get the same error. In order to troubleshoot I think you'll need to provide more details. Also, this type of domain-specific question is far better suited to https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/; you will find many more users there familiar with Trinity, compared to stackoverflow.

Comment: It also would be worth asking on their forum: https://groups.google.com/g/trinityrnaseq-users